# bridging the gap between two tf trees

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, gmapping, turtlebot3, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I am attempting to run a swarm of turtlebot3s from my Ubuntu16.02. I have added namespaces and tf_prefix to relevant .launch files. It seems as though no matter what I change, I can't seem to get rviz to pick up the proper transform, as shown in the following picture: [image: rviz warnings]

and I discovered from view_frames that my two tf trees are persisting as shown here: [image: 2 tf trees] .

Is the only way to fix this by publishing a transform to bridge the two base_footprints? Is this even possible? Sorry - this is all still very new to me and the other questions went over my head a little bit. Anyway, thank you for any advice you can offer!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298446/bridging-the-gap-between-two-tf-trees/) by [AmateurHour](https://answers.ros.org/users/36117/amateurhour/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2018-07-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The quick fix would be to just publish a static transform from `base_footprint` → `bot1_tf/bot1/base_footprint`, like this:

```
rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 base_footprint bot1_tf/bot1/base_footprint 10
```

The more elegant solution would be to make the node that publishes `odom` → `base_footprint` to publish `odom` → `bot1_tf/bot1/base_footprint` instead. It looks like that node is called `bot1/turtlebot3_core`. In the launch file that launches that node, try adding the following parameter:

```
<param name="tf_prefix" value="bot1_tf/bot1/" />
```

If that doesn't work, read the documentation or source code for that node to figure out if there is a parameter that allows you to set the output frame to `bot1_tf/bot1/base_footprint`.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2018-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AmateurHour](https://answers.ros.org/users/36117/amateurhour/) on 2018-07-24**:
So the static transformer works, and connects the trees. Great! However, the tf_prefix solution doesn't solve the problem, and the source code for turtlebot3_core is an .ino file for arduino, and changing relevant names had no effect. Also, no map received.Any other suggestions?Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @AmateurHour,

We recently updated TurtleBot 3's firmware and software to provide users with a solution that uses multiple robots. How to use it is covered in this manual below. If you are using an older version of firmware and software, you will need to update it before you can use it.

http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/applications/#load-multiple-turtlebot3s

---

Originally posted by [Pyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/632/pyo/) with karma: 358 on 2018-07-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AmateurHour](https://answers.ros.org/users/36117/amateurhour/) on 2018-07-24**:
Thank you so much for your reply, I am already up to date and using namespaces + tf_prefix in my launch files to encapsulate rah robot’s nodes and topics. Very useful feature, but still figuring it out! :)